# multiple bootstrap buttons not smoothly hover over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple bootstrap buttons, and their size gets bigger on hover over, but if I hover over them one after another, it is not smooth.
[Here is the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu7y3gz/2/)

```
ol, ul {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
ul#mylist li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
}
ul#mylist li i {
    display: block;
}

ul#mylist li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

How can I make it hover over smoothly like a wave?

Comment: add `.btn-custom { transition: height .25s, width .25s; }`? http://jsfiddle.net/vmu7y3gz/3/

Comment: @MichaelCoker answers go down there.

Comment: @marcel, what's not smooth? Please edit your question to explain the desired effect more clearly. You don't seem to be using any transitions or transformations currently.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i'd rather accept this as the answer to my question but it is in comment section. could you please put it as answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the size changes more fluid, add transition CSS to the properties you're changing on hover: `.btn-custom { transition: height .25s, width .25s; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-transition: width .10s ease-in-out
```

Use Bootstrap Button groups and add the above
to the hover section of your css.
Adjust that time to smooth it out. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rayk216/v98s8wf5/